# Trying to understand margins in LinearLayout inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, padding, margin

I need to have a `LinearLayout` inside a `SrollView` and that `LinearLayout` must have a margin from the `ScrollView`. At first, the only way I could think of to solve that issue was having a `LinearLayout` inside another `LinearLayout` with the margins set on the this last layout. They wouldn't work if they were set in the outer `LinearLayout.`

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@color/layout_color_green">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/layout_color_yellow">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/layout_color_blue">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

My question is: **Why do I need to do this?**

If I had only one `LinearLayout` there would be no margins...

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@color/layout_color_green">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/layout_color_blue">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Then, searching for some similar issue, I found a few layouts which gave me the idea of using padding in the `ScrollView` instead of margin in the `LinearLayout`. This also solves my problem and I don't need a `LinearLayout` inside another one. It's a more elegant solution.

Still, I would like to understand why the simple margin inside the `LinearLayout` doesn't work when inside a `ScrollView`. Because it does work fine if it's not inside a `ScrollView`.

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I digged a little bit into the source code:

`ScrollView` extends `FrameLayout`. This one has some margin issues itself and `ScrollView` is not even trying to solve that. The margins are basically ignored while measuaring.

But in the end it doesn't matter since you should be able to define a padding on the `ScrollView` itself (it's an affirmation, didn't try that). There should be no need for margin for a single child view.

Comment: But the thing is that the margins are not the only problem. If I have the `LinearLayout` height set to `wrap_content` and all children height set to `match_parent`, the children will in fact be `fill_parent`, which is the value that comes from the `ScrollView`. And not `wrap_content` which is the value from the `LinearLayout`, their direct parent. This problem also doesn't happen if I use one `LinearLayout` inside another. So I guess there's more to the `ScrollView` than we know!?

Comment: Yes of course. You forced that behavior with `android:fillViewport="true"`.

Comment: So, do you recommend I go with the padding instead of the margin and set all children of the `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content`?

Comment: I can't recommend padding since this is the only choice ;-)`android:fillViewport="false"` will **not** force the `LinearLayout` to be `fill_parent`, that's it. So it shouldn't be streched and so the children wouldn't neither.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do because this is part of a bigger problem where I have a `GridView` inside a `LinearLayout` which is inside a `ScrollView`. And after searching and reading a lot, I just found out I'm not supposed to have a `GridView` inside a `ScrollView`. I have no idea how to do my UI now... :(

Comment: Ok, I will stop after this comment since this is not the initial question anymore. But I will answer that anyway: That's the same reason why you shouldn't use a `ListView` in a `ScrollView`. 1. They can't ever be `wrap_content` in height. 2. They are already scrollable, it makes no sense to place them in a `ScrollView` which is also vertically scrollable.

Comment: It really is the only way to add margins inside the scrollview, its really anoing you have to hack it like this.

Comment: The only problem is, adding padding to the ScrollView will make the scollbar stick out from the edge of the screen, and will also look ugly as the content will appear to scroll past the top and bottom into nowhere. Hard to explain via text. Try it for yourself to see.

Answer (score 12):

Hello Knickedi and Ricardo Amaral,

Though this answer is marked as solved but I want to put some lights on the issue.

As Knickedi said, ScrollView extends FrameLayout.

So My answer is that You can set the `layout_gravity` of LinearLayout within scrollView and then `layout_margin` will work in LinearLayout as case with linearLayout within FrameLayout.

I had same issue and I've applied this and it worked for me. :)

Example :

```
<ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
</ScrollView>
```