# LinearLayout is getting cut off inside ScrollView Android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have an activity in my app where I would like the user to be able to vertically scroll the content contained inside a `LinearLayout` which in turn is inside a `ScrollView`.  Here is a summary of what the layout XML for this activity looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- a bunch of standard widgets, omitted for brevity -->

            <!-- everything renders but starting in this TextView -->
            <!-- content begins to get truncated -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textSize="20dip"/>

            <!-- this View, really just a trick for a horizontal row, is -->
            <!-- completely cutoff -->
            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@color/green" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I am observing is that content in the inner `LinearLayout` is being cutoff inside the `ScrollView`.  In the final `TextView` above, when it contains little text, then the `View` below it does render in portrait, but does not in landscape.  When this `TextView` contains a lot of text, then it gets cutoff in portrait mode.

I tried the recommendations I found on Stack Overflow.  Adding bottom padding to the `ScrollView` did not resolve the problem, nor did swapping the `ScrollView` for a `NestedScrollView`.

Any helpful suggestions would be welcome.  This is actually turning out to be a blocker.

Comment: add screen shot

Comment: @OussemaAroua I would rather not share the screenshot unless absolutely necessary.  Why do you think it would help?  Basically you would see what I described in the question, except some stuff on the bottom is being cutoff.  I'm hoping you can see a flaw in my layout which I cannot see.

Comment: Try setting some of the inner views heights to match_parent, for example the LinearLayout's

Comment: for more details so we can see real screen

Comment: @stan0 Changing the height of the inner `LinearLayout` to `match_parent` did not fix the problem (or make any noticeable change).  I also tried making the `ScrollView` the outermost tag, but that too didn't seem to work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen then I'd try removing the LinearLayout's margin if you haven't yet

Comment: have you tried `android:fillViewport="true"` ?

Comment: @matoni Adding `fillViewport` to the `ScrollView` seemed to have no effect.

Comment: @stan0 Your suggestion is a good one and was on the right track.  A few other folks have already posted answers already.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Change your inner `LinearLayout`'s margin to padding. Or, if you really need it to be margin (maybe you're using a custom background), wrap your `LinearLayout` in a `FrameLayout`.

The `ScrollView` is taking its height (or, more accurately, it is computing its scrollable range) from the `LinearLayout`. This value doesn't include margins, so your `ScrollView` is going to be "too short" by the sum of the `LinearLayout`'s top and bottom margins.

Comment: In other words, the `ScrollView` is assigned a height which is too short, and then when it comes time for it to actually view its `LinearLayout`, it stops short and truncates the sum of the top and bottom margins, which in my case was 40dp.

Comment: I believe it's as simple as the CSS box model; padding is part of a view's dimensions and margin is not. Check out `ScrollView.canScroll()`... it compares the `ScrollView`'s height to the first child's height.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you made my day.  I'm surprised I could find nothing on this on SO...maybe I was searching for the wrong thing.  Hopefully your answer can help another weary Android developer :-)

Answer (score 0):

The margins are ignored while measuring, See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539755/trying-to-understand-margins-in-linearlayout-inside-a-scrollview)

So you can provide padding to your `ScrollView` and remove margins from your `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- a bunch of standard widgets, omitted for brevity -->

        <!-- everything renders but starting in this TextView -->
        <!-- content begins to get truncated -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="20dip"/>

        <!-- this View, really just a trick for a horizontal row, is -->
        <!-- completely cutoff -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/green" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Also `fill_parent` is deprecated and renamed `match_parent` in API Level 8 and higher**

Comment: Using padding on the scrollview will have some consequences that aren't necessarily desriable. The first is that the content will be clipped by the padding (though you can fix this with `android:clipToPadding="false"`). The other (which I don't know how to fix) is that the scrollbar will be inside the padding.

Comment: Yes I agree, the scrollbars will be inside padding. Thanks for pointing this out